# R merge daily returns to monthly average // two data.frames with different length

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have calculated an output which is on monthly basis and now I want to merge the average daily returns into this output.

My data looks similar to this this:

```
Df1
ID  YMD    R 
1 20160101 1.01
1 20160103 1.02
2 20160101 .98
2 20160103 1.03

Df2
ID YM  Rm 
1 201601 
2 201601
```

Now I want to calculate column Rm using the formula for averaging returns, which is the nth root of the product of the returns within the month.

I tried following, however it did not work:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
setDT(df3)[, Rm := (prod(df3$R)^(1/.N)), by = c(df3$ID, df$YM)]
```

EDIT:

Column Rm should result in

```
Rm
(1.01*1.02)^(1/2)= 1.014987685
(0.98*1.03)^(1/2)= 1.004689007
```

However the length of the days of the month (here = 2) should be variable, as the days are not constant throughout the time series

Comment: Construct a year-month variable in Df1. Merge on this variable.

Comment: Sorry I don't get how to use the merge formula then (`df3 <- merge(df1$YM, df2)`?). I have constructed the YM variable though.

Comment: `df3 <- merge(Df1, Df2, by="YM")` should work if both merging variables have the same name.

Comment: Which is your data set? `Df1`? What is `Df2` here for? What is your desired output? Can you show us please?

Comment: @lmo I did that in my original file but still I can't use my set.dt formula

Comment: @DavidArenburg df1 is my original time series, df 2 is my now into monthly modified time series. I know want to use df2 for my upcoming analysis. df2 has some other variables in it which I have already calculated, but I thought that they are not relevant

Comment: Ok, how `Rm` should look like using your example data?

Comment: If either Df1 or Df2 are data.tables, then `setDT` is not needed. There are a number of typos in that line as well.  Here is a cleaner version, at least `df3[, Rm := (prod(R)^(1/.N)), by = .(ID, YM)]`.

Comment: Yes! It worked, thanks a lot @lmo

Comment: You could also create `Df2` directly from `Df1` using `Df3 <- Df1[, .(R = prod(R)^(1/.N)), by = .(ID, YM = as.integer(substr(YMD, 1, 6)))]` Or you could join them afterwards if your `Df2` is really different `Df2[Df3, R := i.R, on = c(ID = "ID", YM = "YM")]`